# Perl One liner for 3 conditions

Tags: perl, conditional-operator

I have this

```
if($x<10){                                  
    print "child";
}elseif($x>10 && $x<18){
    print "teenage"
}else{
    print "old"
}
```

I want to put in a perl one liner how could i do this please help me

Comment: What do you mean by "perl one liner" in this case?

Comment: i want to do this in one line

Comment: He wants to safe some disk space on server, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conditional operator in Perl

You're looking for the [conditional operator](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/perl/how-use-perl-ternary-operator) (a form of ternary operator which acts as a shorthand if-statement, not Perl-specific):

```
print $age < 10 ? "child" : $age < 18 ? "teenage" : "old";
```

Also, your code treats `10` as old, as it's neither less than nor greater than 10, so I've switched the function to what I think you wanted it to do.

**Reusing the code**

You can turn this into a subroutine for easy reuse:

```
sub determineAgeGroup {
    my $age = $_[0];
    return $age < 10 ? "a child" : $age < 18 ? "a teenager" : "old";
}

my @ages = (5,10,15,20);

foreach my $age (@ages) {
    print "If you're $age you're " . determineAgeGroup($age) . "\n";
}
```

Output to this is:

```
If you're 5 you're a child
If you're 10 you're a teenager
If you're 15 you're a teenager
If you're 20 you're old
```

[Link to working demo](https://eval.in/45721).

Comment: before 8 min i can't wait for 5 min then i will do

Answer (score 5):

You may use the conditional operator. You also need only say `print` once - and I'm also going to change your conditions around, because `10` is neither `>10` nor `<10`, but your code thinks `10` is `old`.

```
print $x<10 ? 'child' : $x<18 ? 'teenage' : 'old';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for my $x ( 5, 15, 55 ) {
    print "$x is ";
    print (($x<10) ? 'child' : ($x>10 && $x<18) ? 'teenage' : 'old');
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No idea why you'd want to but this should work:

```
print (($x<10)?("child"):(($x>10 && $x<18)?("teenage"):("old")))
```

But just because it's short doesn't mean it's better than the original -- compare the difficulty in supporting/debugging the two options.

If you're just playing around the you could also define the strings in an appropriate array and do some maths on the value of `$x` to get a valid array entry.